# Stick wave svg to bottom using react native

Tags: react-native, svg, layout

How to correctly stick SVG wave to bottom/middle of the screen? I am now using `marginTop:50` for the SVG but on different sizes of screen, the result is not good.

```
import {Button, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import Svg, {ClipPath, Defs, G, Path} from "react-native-svg";

export default function LoginScreen() {

    // @ts-ignore
    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
        }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 2,   }} >
                <Svg viewBox="0 0 1440 320" width="100%" height="80" >
                    <Path
                        fill="#8C52FF"
                        d="M0 96l80 32c80 32 240 96 400 80S800 96 960 96s320 96 400 144l80 48V0H0z"
                    />
                </Svg>

                <Svg  viewBox="0 0 1440 320" style={{marginTop:50}}>
                    <Path
                        fill="#8C52FF"
                        d="M0 128l80 21.3c80 21.7 240 63.7 400 69.4C640 224 800 192 960 160l400-80 80-16v256H0z"
                    />
                </Svg>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex:2, backgroundColor: "#8C52FF" , flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:"flex-end" }} >
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.SubmitButtonStyle}
                    activeOpacity = { .5 }
                    onPress={ null }
                >
                    <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> SUBMIT </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.SubmitButtonStyleBottom}
                    activeOpacity = { .5 }
                    onPress={ null }
                >



                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>





        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    SubmitButtonStyle: {

        marginTop:10,
        paddingTop:10,
        paddingBottom:10,
        marginLeft:30,
        marginRight:30,
        backgroundColor:'#FFE7F6',
        borderRadius:20,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#FFE7F6',
        marginBottom:10
    },

    SubmitButtonStyleBottom: {
        marginTop:10,
        paddingTop:25,
        paddingBottom:15,
        marginLeft:30,
        marginRight:30,
        backgroundColor:'#FFE7F6',
        borderRadius:20,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#FFE7F6',
        marginBottom:50
    },
    TextStyle:{
        color:'#8C52FF',
        textAlign:'center',
    }

})
```

This is results what i want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `bottom/middle` ? can you add a screenshot of what you want

Comment: Sure I just added a screenshot.